# Comma in arrow of tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
X \ar[r, "(1,0)"] & A
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Does not compile. However removing the comma inside the " " makes it work. Why and how to have a comma here?

Comment: I can see two commas here and you only mention one. Which one? And please, consider editing your question to give a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @SebGlav The one inside the " "

Comment: Untested `"{(1,0)}"`?

Comment: @daleif It works

Comment: @CarLaTeX i have to say i like your name :)

Comment: @Carla_display Hi Carla, I'm Carla!

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you, i marked this question as duplicate.

Comment: @Carla_display I'm sorry :-) in fact it is a duplicate :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano On the contrary, thank you for finding a duplicate and telling it. You should not say sorry for that, you did something helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do that, but you lose the spacing after the comma.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
X \ar[r, "(1{,}0)"] & A
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was about to suggest `X \ar[r, "{(1,\,0)}"]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is the old syntax for arrows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
X \ar{r}{(1,0)} & A
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]